# We added thousands of pages at once to our website, and we have lost our SEO ranking, what should I do?

Tags: seo

A month ago we add an archive of tens of thousands of pages to our website at once. Now we have lost SEO ranking significantly.

What can I do to resolve this issue ASAP?

Comment: 10,000 quality pages? doubt it... Quality, not quantity or face the wrath of the [**Panda**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Panda) Slap.

Comment: @SimonHayter I know I did something wrong. Now, what can I do?

Comment: Pretty obvious... remove the thin or low quality pages then wait for Panda to refresh. Sadly... its going to take you several months for you to recover because it takes time to remove 10,000 URLS from Google's index because you need to wait for the Googlebot to return to these pages a couple of times each before Google drops them and only then will Google remove the penalty placed on your site. Bottomline is... there is no quick fix other than forcing Google's hand using robots.txt which I don't recommend.

Comment: @SimonHayter Remove them and return 404 status code? Is it okay to return many 404 status at once?

Comment: Yep, 404 is perfectly fine.